# How to find out the value of an input which already changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch

I have3 inputs which each of which has a specific value.

```html
<input type="text" id="inputType" v-model="add_sale.type">
<input type="text" id="inputId" v-model="add_sale.id">
<input type="text" dir="auto" v-model="add_sale.name" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Material" readonly style="background: #fff;">
```

I change any of the input values like this:

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return{
      material:{
        name: "niaz",
        id: 1,
        type: "human"
      },
      add_sale: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.getElementById("inputName").value = this.material.name;
    document.getElementById("inputId").value = this.material.id;
    document.getElementById("inputType").value = this.material.type;
  }
})
```

Now I need to watch the values that changed before.
I want to know if there is any way to find out what is the value of one of the inputs which changed before and change the name input to Alex if the type was human.

Comment: This isn't the way to Vue.  Set the values on `add_sale` in `mounted` instead of changing the DOM manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude,

If I understand you correctly.
you are looking for something to track your previous value.
with `Vuejs` you can do it very easily. and one more important thing. when you are using `vue` you don't need to be dependent on `vanilla Javascript`

so what you are looking for is something is gonna be like this,

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return{
      type : null,
      id: null, 
      name: null, 
      add_sale: {}
    }
  },
  watch: {
    type(oldvalue, newvalue) {
        //do whatever you want to do
    },
    id(oldvalue, newvalue) {
        //do whatever you want to do
    },
    name(oldvalue, newvalue) {
        //do whatever you want to do
    },
  },
  mounted() {
     this.type = 'something' //initial the value
     this.id = 1243 //intial value
     this.name = 'name' //initial value
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputType" v-model="type">
<input type="text" id="inputId" v-model="id">
<input type="text" dir="auto" v-model="name" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Material" readonly style="background: #fff;">
```

so you can do it easily with vuejs `watch` which pretty much work like on change event listener.

and the parameter `oldvalue` where you will have the previous data, `newvalue` is the current data you change

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just one more thing. Is this any way to trigger change without typing in the input?

Comment: well, nothing like I am aware of. but you can always use the 
events. like , onchange, onkeyup which will be responsible for all type of occurrence on the dom